# Get Author-name from Book-class simple

Tags: java

So, I'm new with Object oriented programming. I'm doing the next excercises:

1. Given a class Book defined as having the following attributes:

   ```
   Author author;
   String title;
   int noOfPages;
   boolean fiction;
   ```

   write standard `get`/`set` method headers for each of these attributes.
2. [Coding] Actually code and compile the Book class based on the attributes and `get`/`set` methodscalled for in exercise 1.

This is my code:

```
public class Author {

    //private variable
    private String name;
    private String gender;  
    //constructor
    public Author (String name, String gender){
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;   
    }
    //getters
    public String getName(){
        return name;  
    }
    public String getGender(){
        return gender;
    }
public class Book {

    //private variables
    private Author author;
    private String title;
    private int noOfPages;
    private boolean fiction;

    //constructor
    public Book(String title, int noOfPages, boolean fiction){
        this.author=new Author ("Jacquie Barker","Female");
        this.title = title;
        this.noOfPages=noOfPages;
        this.fiction = fiction;    
    }

    //getters
    public Author getAuthorsName(){
        return this.author;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public int getNoOfPages(){
        return noOfPages;
    }

    public boolean getFiction(){
        return fiction;
    }

    //setters
    public void setAuthor(Author newAuthor){
        author=newAuthor;
    }
    public void setTitle (String title){
        this.title=title;
    }
    public void setNoOfPages(int noOfpages){
        this.noOfPages=noOfpages;
    }
    public void setfiction(boolean fiction){
        this.fiction=false;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Title: " + this.title + "\n"+"Author: " + this.author + "\n" +
               "No. of pages: " + this.noOfPages + "\n" + "Fiction: " + this.fiction;
    }
}
```

Here is the excerpt of main:

```
Title: Beginning in Java Objects

Author: book.Author@15db9742

No. of pages: 300

Fiction: true
```

As you can see, the program does not print the name of the author.

I appreciate all help!

Comment: What did you expect it to print and why?

Comment: Override the `toString` method. It's called implicitly when you concatenate an `Author` with a `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the author's name, change this to:

```
public Author getAuthorsName(){
    return this.author;
}
```

to:

```
public String getAuthorsName(){
    return this.author.getName();
}
```

Currently you are returning an object of class `Author` from your method, so to get the author's name, you either need to call `author.getName()` in the calling code or change your existing method to return the author's name as explained above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and helpful response

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here. First, you could simply refactor the code in your `Book.toString()` method to print the actual name of the author:

```
public String toString(){
    return "Title: " + this.title + "\n"+"Author: " + this.author.getName() + "\n" +
           "No. of pages: " + this.noOfPages + "\n" + "Fiction: " + 
}
```

Second, you could override the `toString()` method in the `Author` class to return the author's name.  Then, you can leave your `Book.toString()` method as it is, because Java will call this `toString()` method when you try to print the `Author` object:

```
public class Author {
    // print the author's name when an Author object appears in a print statement
    public String toString() {
       return this.name;
    }
}
```

and then as you were:

```
public class Book {
    public String toString(){
        return "Title: " + this.title + "\n"+"Author: " + this.author + "\n" +
           "No. of pages: " + this.noOfPages + "\n" + "Fiction: " + this.fiction;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your extremely helpful and detailed response to my questions!

Answer (score 1):

You should be implementing toString in Author class.

```
    public class Author {

        //private variable
        private String name;
        private String gender;  
        //constructor
        public Author (String name, String gender){
            this.name = name;
            this.gender = gender;   
        }
        ...
        public String toString() {
          return "Name " + name + "\t Gender: " + gender + "\n"; //Somethign like this.
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ or NetBeans, you can let them generate these standard getters and setters. Explore the menus.

This way, there will be no typos (as in `setfiction`, the `f` should be capital).

Since you are a beginner, you should first write them yourself and then let them auto-generate, so you can compare your solution.